# Objective-C blocks

Tags: objective-c, block

Trying to understand how blocks working in objective-c. Got next question while reading apple's docs ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html))

Here is an example how we should no use blocks:

```
void dontDoThis() {
    void (^blockArray[3])(void);  // an array of 3 block references

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        blockArray[i] = ^{ printf("hello, %d\n", i); };
        // WRONG: The block literal scope is the "for" loop.
    }
}
```

But how we could get 3 different blocks that will print "hello, 0", "hello, 1" and "hello, 2"? I tried many different ways but every time I got "hello, 2" three times.

Comment: Why not pass an argument to the block?

Comment: It seems like this should work as he expected. The page [Blocks and Variables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1) says "Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are captured as const variables.
Their values are taken at the point of the block expression within the program."

Comment: When I ran the above code in an ARC project, it gave me 0,1,2 than 2,2,2. So it seems like in ARC, this behaves in a different way. bbum has explained this in his post now.

Comment: @H2CO3 I just want to know the ways it could be done.

Answer (score 8):

A block starts out life on the stack and, thus, a block's lifespan is only as long as the scope it is declared in.

The body of a for() loop -- the body of the loop in the {}s -- is a scope in and of itself.  Thus, your code is putting a reference to something on the stack [the block] into a variable in the surrounding scope [the language array].

You need to copy the block to the heap to have it survive:

```
void dontDoThis() {
    void (^blockArray[3])(void);  // an array of 3 block references

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        blockArray[i] = [^{ printf("hello, %d\n", i); } copy];
    }
}
```

If not using ARC, you would also need to `-release` the copied blocks at some point.

You might find this [weblog post handy](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/basic-blocks/) (I wrote it shortly after Blocks were made public).  This one goes into a [few tips, tricks, and gotchas](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/08/29/blocks-tips-tricks/).

---

Wait -- yeah -- you're correct.  There is magic going on in the ARC compiler that is causing the blocks to seemingly be on the heap magically.   However, I can't find anything in the LLVM documentation that explicitly documents this behavior.   If you turn off ARC, you'll see the output be something like 2,2,2 instead of 0,1,2.

This is somewhat new behavior.   I wouldn't rely on this behavior until someone can find the explicit note in the compiler that defines exactly how this is supported.

---

```
@autoreleasepool {
    void (^blockArray[3])(void);  // an array of 3 block references

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        void (^block)(void) = ^{ printf("hello, %d\n", i); };
        NSLog(@"%p", block);
        blockArray[i] = block;
        NSLog(@"%p", blockArray[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) blockArray[i]();
}
```

Outputs:

```
2012-12-24 16:15:36.752 jkdfjkfdjkdfjk[70708:303] 0x7fff5fbff838
2012-12-24 16:15:36.755 jkdfjkfdjkdfjk[70708:303] 0x100108160
2012-12-24 16:15:36.758 jkdfjkfdjkdfjk[70708:303] 0x7fff5fbff838
2012-12-24 16:15:36.759 jkdfjkfdjkdfjk[70708:303] 0x100108000
2012-12-24 16:15:36.760 jkdfjkfdjkdfjk[70708:303] 0x7fff5fbff838
2012-12-24 16:15:36.760 jkdfjkfdjkdfjk[70708:303] 0x100102e70
hello, 0
hello, 1
hello, 2
```

Thus, the block is created on the stack and copied to the heap automatically on the assignment outside of the scope of the for() loop.

A similar test also reveals that the block will be copied when passed as an argument to NSArray's addObject:.

Comment: Regarding this section in your second link, `2) Blocks are created on the stack. Careful.`, I tried the same sample code without copy and I got 0,1,2 as the output instead of 2,2,2. Is there any change to this in ARC or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Also in that code if I use `__weak Blocky b[3];` I am getting 2,2,2. So by default, it looks it is doing a copy in ARC, I am not sure though.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. This was one thing I remembered seeing when I saw the question from OP. He may not be using ARC. So just wanted to confirm that. +1.

Comment: Honestly, the behavior came as a bit of a surprise.  I don't think that was the original behavior.  In general, ARC is trending towards more and more bullet proof behavior.  I have a question out to the lead architect.

Comment: Yes, even I didn't expect that, especially after it was explicitly mentioned in Apple documentation. But that was how it was working in ARC project.

Comment: When I first read your results about the ARC, I thought it had something to do with storing it in a variable of block type, and that causing ARC to copy it automatically. However, when I tried storing it directly into a variable of type `id`, it still copied it. By the way, I am not getting the output you are getting -- I am getting that the block was already copied on storing in the variable, so both prints print the same address (I am using XCode 4.5, maybe you have a newer version).

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If you really wanted to get this to work you could use an `NSMutableArray` instead of a C array.</strike>

    <strike>NSMutableArray *blocks = [NSMutableArray array];</strike>

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  blocks[i] = ^{ printf("hello %d\n", i); };
}
```

<strike>By adding them to an `NSMutableArray` they will be copied off of the stack and onto the heap allowing them to outlive the scope of the `for` loop.</strike>

As @bbum points out the above does not work, I took the idea that blocks `just work` with ARC too far.

You would need to actively copy the blocks for them to work... so the following should work

```
NSMutableArray *blocks = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  blocks[i] = [^{ printf("hello %d\n", i); } copy];
}
```

Comment: Won't work;   not even with the new array syntax.  Arrays don't copy objects put into them.

Comment: Cool.  Blocks are not automatically copied when passed as an argument because the compiler can't know if the thing being called is going to just use the block directly, copy it or store it directly.  Automatically copying the block on the way in would be a potentially massive amount of overhead.

Comment: See my answer;  blocks are sometimes automatically allocated on the heap under ARC, it seems.